# Rotate CAEmitterCell content based on Animation Direction

Tags: ios, calayer, caemitterlayer, caemittercell

Using CAEmitterLayer and Cell to show particles that have direction sensitive content image (an arrow).

Want the content (arrow image) to point in the direction the cell is moving.

Here is code for having all the arrows move from outside edge toward center. How to rotate image so the image points in direction of movement:

```
emitterLayer = [CAEmitterLayer layer];
emitterLayer.emitterPosition = self.view.center;
emitterLayer.emitterSize = self.view.bounds.size;
emitterLayer.emitterMode = kCAEmitterLayerOutline;
emitterLayer.emitterShape = kCAEmitterLayerRectangle;

CAEmitterCell* arrow = [CAEmitterCell emitterCell];
arrow.birthRate     = 10;
arrow.velocity      = 100;
arrow.emissionLatitude = M_PI;
arrow.scale         = 0.5;
arrow.lifetime      = 2;
arrow.contents = (id) [[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrowOutline.png"] CGImage];


emitterLayer.emitterCells = @[arrow];
[self.view.layer addSublayer:emitterLayer];
```

How to get the content image to adjust based on direction of cell movement?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using 4 different CAEmitterLayers one for each direction where emitterPosition is each edge of the screen and emitterSize is length of given edge.

If there is better solution please share.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this simple solution! I haven't thought of that.